# laravel reset password for a logged in user

Tags: laravel

I am using the default laravel 5.1 reset password functionality.
Not logged in user,it work successfully.
But,if I logged in and redirect to the password reset route (/password/email/) ,it will be automatically redirected to the route(/home)
I think Laravel has built on the user's judgment,but I don't know how to do.